# How can i get String result in stringPattern value birdantantcatbirdcat

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i have dataDic that is an array {"ant","bird","cat"}

dataDic is array of word that i want to search on stringPattern

I want to use dataDic to get word result from stringPattern = birdantantcatbirdcat

Ex1.
dataDic = {"ant","bird","cat"}
answer is {bird,ant,ant,cat,bird,cat}
Ex2.
dataDic = {"ant","cat"}
answer is {ant,ant,cat,cat}

this is my code
`private static String stringTest="birdantantcatbirdcat";
    private static List dicListWord;
    private static ListresultString = new ArrayList<>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    dicListWord = new ArrayList<>();
    dicListWord.add("ant");
    dicListWord.add("bird");
    dicListWord.add("cat");
    String[] data = stringTest.split("");

    for (String dataDic:dicListWord) {
        String [] wordList = dataDic.split("");
        String foundWord = "";
        for (String charTec:data) {
            for (String dicWord:wordList) {
                if(charTec.equals(dicWord)){
                    foundWord = foundWord.concat(charTec);
                    if(dataDic.equals(foundWord)){
                        resultString.add(foundWord);
                        foundWord = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (String w1:data) {
        for (String result:resultString) {
                System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}`
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

and Result that i run is

{ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,antbird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird,ant,ant,bird,bird}

Comment: Can you explain why exactly you expect those answers for the given dataDic? Also please include some code that you have already tried so we can help you with where you're stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to store the position of a word as the key and the word itself as the value as you navigate the string to find matches for the word. The reason why you need to choose a `TreeMap` is that it is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys which is an important aspect for your requirement.

Your requirement states that the words in the resulting list should be in the order of their occurrences in the string.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = List.of("ant", "bird", "cat");
        String str = "birdantantcatbirdcat";
        System.out.println(getMatchingWords(words, str));
    }

    static List<String> getMatchingWords(List<String> words, String str) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
        for (String word : words) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                map.put(matcher.start(), matcher.group());
            }
        }
        return map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[bird, ant, ant, cat, bird, cat]
```

Comment: This solution iterate over a dictionary which can be very large.

Answer (score 0):

This is a word break problem and can be solved using a depth-first search. But it is wise to check before if the given string pattern is breakable or not to get better run-time in scenario where we have given a long string pattern that doesn't match any words in the dictionary.

```
public class P00140_Word_Break_II {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "catsanddog";
    List<String> wordDict = Arrays.asList("cat", "cats", "and", "sand", "dog");
    P00140_Word_Break_II solution = new P00140_Word_Break_II();
    List<String> results = solution.wordBreak(input, wordDict);
    System.out.println(results);
    String input1 = "birdantantcatbirdcat";
    List<String> wordDict1 = Arrays.asList("ant","bird","cat");
    List<String> results1 = solution.wordBreak(input1, wordDict1);
    System.out.println(results1);

}

public List<String> wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
    Set<String> dict = new HashSet<>(wordDict);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0 || !isbreakable(s, dict)) {
        return result;
    }
    helper(s, 0, new StringBuilder(), dict, result);
    return result;
}

public void helper(String s, int start, StringBuilder item, Set<String> dict, List<String> results) {

    if (start >= s.length()) {
        results.add(item.toString());
        return;
    }

    if (start != 0) {
        item.append(" ");
    }

    for (int i = start; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String temp = s.substring(start, i + 1);
        if (dict.contains(temp)) {
            item.append(temp);
            helper(s , i+1 , item , dict , results);
            item.delete(item.length() + start - i - 1 , item.length());
        }
    }
    if(start!=0) item.deleteCharAt(item.length()-1);
}

private boolean isbreakable(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    boolean[] dp = new boolean[s.length() + 1];
    dp[0] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            String subString = s.substring(j, i);
            if (dp[j] && dict.contains(subString)) {
                dp[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[s.length()];
}
```

}